# How to disable no-extend-native warning in React?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

[image]

I've edited my local `.eslintrc.js` file and made `"no-extend-native": "off"` adjustment but it doesn't seem to take effect on the project. What should I do to disable this warning?

Comment: Isn't `0` or `false` the right format?

Comment: 0 or false doesn't work either...

Comment: But are you sure your eslint conf is properly read? If you hack other configuration options is that working?
Maybe you are using the `.eslintrc` file while you are also the _eslint_ section in your package.json?

Comment: I am not sure. How do I find out which eslintrc file I am using.